# how can i make Flask WTF recognize my selectField choices populated with jquery ajax?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

So, the deal is i'm loading my **car_brand selectfield choices** with a response from some car brand **API**, i'm also loading my **car_model selectfield choices** with another car models **API** asynchronously using **jquery ajax** base on brand selected, and it seems to be working fine and populating the **car_model selectfield choices** as i want, but on submit of this form **Flask WTF** does not recognize the **selectfield choices/value** for the car model populated with **jquery ajax**. How can i go about this.**

This is the validation error i'm getting **NOT A VALID CHOICE****

This is my **postad route** where i make a request to the API for manufacturers/brand and also populate the Car table in the database

```
@app.route('/postad',methods=\['GET', 'POST'\])
@login_required
def postad():
form = CarAdForm()
\# Make a request to the API for manufacturers
url = 'https://private-d6891-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/manufacturers'
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response_body = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

    # Load the JSON response and extract manufacturer names
    response_body = json.loads(response_body.read())
    response_body = [item['name'] for item in response_body if 'name' in item]
    
    # Sort the manufacturer names alphabetically
    response_body = sorted(response_body)
    
    # Add a default choice to the beginning of the manufacturer list
    default_choice = ("Select Brand")
    response_body.insert(0, default_choice)
    
    form.car_brand.choices = [(choice, choice.capitalize()) for choice in response_body]
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Create a new Car object with the form data
        car = Car(
            car_brand=form.car_brand.data,
            car_model=form.car_model.data,
            year=form.year.data,
            types_of_gear=form.types_of_gear.data,
            condition=form.condition.data,
            mileage=form.mileage.data,
            fuel_type=form.fuel_type.data,
            price=form.price.data,
            phone=form.phone.data,
            city=form.city.data,
            car_img_caption=form.caption.data,
            car_desc=form.ad_desc.data,
            seller_id=current_user
        )
    
        # Add the new Car object to the database session and commit changes
        db.session.add(car)
        db.session.commit()
    
        # car_id = Car.query.get(id)
        #
        # car_photos = Car(
        #     car_id=car_id,
        #     photo_path=form.year.data
        #
        # )
        # # Add the new Car object to the database session and commit changes
        # db.session.add(car_photos)
        # db.session.commit()
        flash('Your Ads has been added successfully', 'success')
    
    
    return render_template('postad.html', form=form, response_body=response_body)
```

This is my **get_models route ** where i make a request to the API for car models and also filter them base on the car brand chosen*

```
@app.route('/get_models', methods=['POST','GET'])
def get_models():
    brand = request.form.get('brand')
    # Make a request to the API for models
    url = 'https://private-d6891-carsapi1.apiary-mock.com/cars'

    response = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response_body = urllib.request.urlopen(response)
    models=[]

    # Load the JSON response and extract model names
    response_body = json.loads(response_body.read())
    for item in response_body:
         if 'make' in item:
             if item['make'] == f"{brand}":
                models.append(item['model'])


    # To access the models for a specific brand, use the brand name as the key
    return jsonify({"models": models})
```

This is my javascript code to send the car_brand/manufacturer to **get_model route**

```
$('#car_brand').change(function() {
                // Get the selected brand
                var selectedBrand = $(this).val();

                // Send an Ajax request to /get_models to fetch model choices based on the selected brand
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/get_models',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: { brand: selectedBrand },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        // Update the model field's options based on the response
                        var modelSelect = $('#car_model');
                        modelSelect.empty(); // Clear existing options
                        $.each(data.models, function(index, model) {
                            modelSelect.append(new Option(model, model));
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

This is how i defined my Car Flaskform class

```
class CarAdForm(FlaskForm):
    car_brand = SelectField('Car Brand', choices=[], validators=[DataRequired()])
    car_model = SelectField('Car Model', choices=[], validators=[DataRequired()])
    year = StringField('Year', validators=[DataRequired()])
    types_of_gear = SelectField('Types of Gear', choices=[('', 'Select gear type'),('Auto', 'Auto'), ('Manual', 'Manual')],
                               validators=[DataRequired()])
    condition = SelectField('Select Condition', choices=[('', 'Select condition'),('New', 'New'), ('Used', 'Used')],
                            validators=[DataRequired()])
    mileage = StringField('Mileage (km)', validators=[DataRequired()])
    fuel_type = SelectField('Fuel Type', choices=[('', 'Select fuel type'),('Petrol', 'Petrol'), ('Diesel', 'Diesel'), ('CNG', 'CNG')],
                            validators=[DataRequired()])
    price = StringField('Price (AED)', validators=[DataRequired()])
    city = SelectField('City', choices=[('', 'Select city'),('Dubai', 'Dubai'),('Abu-Dhabi', 'Abu Dhabi'),('Sharjah', 'Sharjah'),('Ajman', 'Ajman'),('Ras-Al-Khaimah', 'Ras Al Khaimah'),('Fujairah', 'Fujairah'),('Umm-al-Quwain', 'Umm al-Quwain')], validators=[DataRequired()])
    phone = StringField('Phone Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    ad_img = MultipleFileField('Add Images (Multiple)', validators=[DataRequired()])
    caption = TextAreaField('Add Caption')
    ad_desc = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Post Ad')
```